# Bootstrap carousel stops after last slide in Shopify

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, shopify

I'm re-building an existing site using the Shopify platform, and integrating elements from Bootstrap, such as the carousel. Everything works pretty well except the carousel, which is failing to slide to the first slide, after the last one.

I have added the following into the head of the Shopify theme file:

```
{{ '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js' | script_tag }}

{{ '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css' | stylesheet_tag }}

{{ '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js' | script_tag }}
```

And this is the code for the carousel:

```
    <div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->

      <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="item slideshow1 active">
            <a href="#">
                <div id="caption-container">
                    <div id="carousel-caption" class="slide-right">                     
            <a href="http://gorilla-foodco.com/shop.html" class="btn btn-brown" role="button">Cane it, cane it...</a> 
                    </div>  
                </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="item slideshow2">
            <a href="#">
                <div id="caption-container">
                    <div id="carousel-caption" class="slide-right">                     
            <a href="http://www.gorilla-foodco.com/shop.html#!/Gorilla-Food-Co-Whole-Dark-Chia-Seeds-400g/p/64622245/category=19687050" class="btn btn-purple" role="button">Hells yeah!</a> 
                    </div>  
                </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="item slideshow3">
            <a href="#">
                <div id="caption-container">
                    <div id="carousel-caption" class="slide-right">                     
            <a href="http://gorilla-foodco.com/shop.html#!/Gorilla-Food-Co-Natural-Almonds-Whole-Raw-800g-Bulk-Pack/p/63540629/category=19687049" class="btn btn-brown" role="button">GIMME SOME.</a> 
                    </div>  
                </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="item slideshow4">
            <a href="#">
                <div id="caption-container">
                    <div id="carousel-caption" class="slide-right">                     
            <a href="http://gorilla-foodco.com/shop.html#!/Oats-Flours-&-Grains/c/19687048/offset=0&sort=priceAsc" class="btn btn-gold" role="button">Roll that shiz...</a> 
                    </div>  
                </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="item slideshow5">
            <a href="#">
                <div id="caption-container">
                    <div id="carousel-caption" class="slide-right">                     
            <a href="http://gorilla-foodco.com/downloads/Gorilla-Food-Co-Figure-Out-The-Flames-Wallpaper-HD.jpg" class="btn btn-orange" role="button">Hey man, it's free! </a> 
                    </div>  
                </div>  
        </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="prev">
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="next">
      </a>
    </div>
```

This works fine on the existing site and I haven't changed anything other than adding the css and js links to the Shopify theme as described above.

Any ideas?

Thanks, Ian

Comment: Hi, Can you give us the link to your shopify store where you are installing the carousel. Make sure its not password protected. That way i will be able to check the issue properly. Right now my guess is that you added the class "active" to first child which is not necessary. 
Regards

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Sure, the link is: https://gorilla-food-co.myshopify.com I did try removing the "active" class however this caused the carousel to stop working completely. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now your carousel control (left / right arrow ) links are inside "carousel-inner" div.  You need to move them out of that div to make the carousel work properly. Below is corrected code.

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/52e07p91/2/

```
<div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->

  <div class="carousel-inner">

    <div class="item slideshow1 active">
      <a href="#">
      </a>
      <div id="caption-container">
        <a href="#">
        </a>
        <div id="carousel-caption" class="slide-right">
          <a href="#">
          </a><a href="http://gorilla-foodco.com/shop.html" class="btn btn-brown" role="button">Cane it, cane it...</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item slideshow2">
      <a href="#">
      </a>
      <div id="caption-container">
        <a href="#">
        </a>
        <div id="carousel-caption" class="slide-right">
          <a href="#">
          </a><a href="http://www.gorilla-foodco.com/shop.html#!/Gorilla-Food-Co-Whole-Dark-Chia-Seeds-400g/p/64622245/category=19687050" class="btn btn-purple" role="button">Hells yeah!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item slideshow3">
      <a href="#">
      </a>
      <div id="caption-container">
        <a href="#">
        </a>
        <div id="carousel-caption" class="slide-right">
          <a href="#">
          </a><a href="http://gorilla-foodco.com/shop.html#!/Gorilla-Food-Co-Natural-Almonds-Whole-Raw-800g-Bulk-Pack/p/63540629/category=19687049" class="btn btn-brown" role="button">GIMME SOME.</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item slideshow4">
      <a href="#">
      </a>
      <div id="caption-container">
        <a href="#">
        </a>
        <div id="carousel-caption" class="slide-right">
          <a href="#">
          </a><a href="http://gorilla-foodco.com/shop.html#!/Oats-Flours-&amp;-Grains/c/19687048/offset=0&amp;sort=priceAsc" class="btn btn-gold" role="button">Roll that shiz...</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item slideshow5">
      <a href="#">
      </a>
      <div id="caption-container">
        <a href="#">
        </a>
        <div id="carousel-caption" class="slide-right">
          <a href="#">
          </a><a href="http://gorilla-foodco.com/downloads/Gorilla-Food-Co-Figure-Out-The-Flames-Wallpaper-HD.jpg" class="btn btn-orange hoverZoomLink" role="button">Hey man, it's free! </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control active" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="prev">
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="next">
  </a>
  <!-- end of carousel -->
</div>
```

Comment: That's brilliant, works perfect now. Thank you so much for your help!